Remove synonym [compiler] from [compiler-construction] tag
About 10 years ago, the [compiler] tag was renamed to [compiler-construction] to avoid "tag misuse". That was a good idea.
However, since the tag compiler is still a synonym to the compiler-construction tag, there is often misuse of the tag. It would be better to not have the compiler as a synonym. People usually add the compiler-tag when they have questions about a specific compiler (and this was explicitly listed as the problem with the tag).
Comment, from the above linked 10 year old question, still a recurring problem:

I agree with Ganesh that the synonym should be removed. The tag keeps being misused. I've seen some cases where the tag was removed by the OP shortly after asking the question, but there's also plenty of cases where the tag is simply kept until I or someone else remove it.

Can we remove the compiler synonym from the compiler-construction tag? Such that questions not about "Compiler Construction", does not get tagged compiler-construction?

If it is removed as a synonym, won't the tag inevitably get recreated and end up misused just as before?

@kmdreko the tag [compiler-construction] would not be misused that way, since it has a longer and specific name now, after the renaming. The tag [compiler], if created, would be a more manageable problem.

...sure, why not.  Done.  If it goes badly and people keep recreating it, we can just merge them again and be back where we apparently are today.
Also, if anyone sees the tag get recreated, it should probably be ...un-recreated.
This leaves two synonyms,  compiler-design (clearly fine) and compilers (less clearly fine).  I'm leaving compilers for two reasons: 1) it seems to be an order of magnitude less prone to misuse (4290 renames on "compiler" vs. 426 for "compilers"), and 2) "compilers" is not a substring of "compiler-construction", so someone who just quickly types "compilers" and looks at the results should find compiler-construction.  If it's still a problem, we can do something janky like creating a synonym for "compilers-construction" or something to that effect.
